# How do I store this in an adjacency list for graphs in python?

Tags: python, adjacency-list

Suppose I have a text file containing this:

```
0 1 4
0 2 3
1 4 7
5 3 8
```

The columns represent:

1. a vertex
2. another vertex
3. the distance between these two vertices.

For example, in the first line in the text file, 4 is the distance between points 0 and 1.

So how would I store the vertices and distances in an adjacency list in python?

Comment: Watch this tutorial , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsAUil2eBZs&t=471s

Answer (score 7):

In graph theory, an [adjacent-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), is a collection of unordered lists used to represent a graph. Each list describes the set of neighbors of a vertex in the graph.

Since you are talking about adjacent list of weighted graph, you need to define a structure to store both `vertex` and `weight`. A graph theory or data structure way to implement adjacent list is like this:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, v, w, next=None):
        self.v = v
        self.w = w
        self.next = next
    ...

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self, head=None)
        self.head = head

    def add_node():
        pass
    ...
```

Here `Node` class is the base element to compose `LinkedList` and `LinkedList` is used to represent adjacent list of one vertex. I do not implement the whole classes for you. See [python-linked-list](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/implementing-a-singly-linked-list-in-python/).

Assuming your graph is **directed**, the adjacent list of this graph is:

```
0 -> [1:4]-> [2:3]
1 -> [4:7]
2 -> []
3 -> []
4 -> []
5 -> [3:8]
```

in which, `0 -> [1:4] -> [2:3]` represents the adjacent list of vertex `0`, which contains two edges: `0->1` with weight `4` and `0->2` with weight `3`. `[1:4]` could be described by class `Node`, and the whole row could be represented by class `LinkedList`.  Check [weighted-graph-adjacent-list](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/11-Graph/weighted.html) for more information.

To represent the whole graph, you can simply use a list of `LinkedList`, e.g.,

```
g = [LinkedList_for_0, LinkedList_for_1, ...]
```

In this approach, `g[i]` will be the adjacent list of vertex `i`.

To build the whole graph, you can iterate over all edges:

```
g = [[] for v in range(number_of_vertex)]
for f, t, w in edges:
    g[f].add_node(Node(t,w))
```

In above, as I said, **it's a more data structure way** to implement the adjacent list. If you would to practice your understanding of data structure and graph theory knowledge, you can try this way. But, actually, unlike `C/C++` `array` type (fixed size), python `list` is a mutable type, you can do operations like add, delete on a python `list`.  So `LinkedList` is actually unnecessarily needed. We can redefine the these classes in a **pythonic way**:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, v, w):
        self.v = v
        self.w = w
```

Here, the `Node` class do not contain `next` member. So the adjacent list can be represented as a list of `Node`, e.g., adjacent list of vertex `0`:

```
[Node(1,4), Node(2,3)]
```

And the whole graph can be represented as a two dimensional list (Here we assume this is a **undirected** graph.):

```
[
 [Node(1,4), Node(2,3)],
 [Node(0,4), Node(4,7)],
 [Node(0,3)],
 [Node(5,8)],
 [Node(1,7)],
 [Node(3,8)]
]
```

The python way algorithm:

```
g = [[] for v in range(number_of_vertex)]
for f,t,w in edges:
    g[f].append(Node(t,w))
    g[t].append(Node(f,w))
```

Note: you need to add a new node for **both ends of an edge**.

In practice, when handling graph problems, I believe edge-list or sparse matrix is the most common representation. So if it possible, I would suggest you used this kind of representation.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! What if my graph is undirected?

Comment: If your graph is undirected, when iterate over an edge `a, b, w`, you should add a new node `[b,w]` for vertex `a`'s adjacent list and a new node `[a, w]` for vertex `b`'s adjacent list.

Comment: You probably should delete the whole first part about linked lists. It looks like your second part uses an Edge which you named Node.

Comment: @KennyOstrom The first part is trying to describe the problem in a data structure way. About the naming: an adjacent list of a vertex `v` is a list of neighbors, which are vertexes. In the second part, the adjacent list of a vertex `f` is represented as `[Node(t1,w1), Node(t2, w2)]`. `Node(t1, w1)` means vertex `t1` is a neighbor of vertex `f` and the edge `<f, t1>` is weighted `w1`.

Comment: @KennyOstrom the first part is the most interesting part of this answer. It tells the basic approach to build the adjacency list (that's why one studies the Data Structures), the second part is just an abstraction over the first part.

Comment: @rojeeer nice answer, just one point which conflicts in your answer as you mentioned "`unlike C/C++ array type (fixed size), python list is a mutable type`" but the arrays in c/c++ are also mutable. the difference lies in the fact that they can't grow dynamically unless to make them grow.

Answer (score 5):

Nested dictionaries are a natural way to represent adjacency lists. Dictionaries are convenient in this situation because they can represent sparse mappings better than lists, and allow efficient lookups.

```
adjacency_list = {}
for line in open(file):
    from, to, weight = map(int, line.split())
    adjacency_list.setdefault(from, {})[to] = weight
    adjacency_list.setdefault(to, {})[from] = weight  # for undircted graph add reverse edges
```

To get the weight of an edge between node `i` and `j`, you'd lookup `adjacency_list.get(i, {}).get(j)` (which will return `None` if the edge doesn't exist).

If you didn't want to deal with `setdefault` and `get`, you might want to  use a `defaultdict` for at least the top-level dictionary. If you initialize with `adjacency_list = defaultdict(dict)`, then setting the weights would just be `adjacency_list[from][to] = weight` (the inner dictionaries will be created automatically whenever they're needed).

Answer (score 2):

you can use this script for weighted-graph !

```
from collections import defaultdict

adj = defaultdict(list)

content = open('input.txt', 'r').readlines()

for line in content:
    u, v, w = map(int, line.strip().split(' '))
    # if edge is on-way
    adj[u].append((v, w))
    # otherwise,
    adj[u].append((v, w))
    adj[v].append((u, w))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) library, it's awesome and easy to use.

From [the docs](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/introduction.html#nodes-and-edges), you can have edge attributes storing any value of interest - distance, in your case:

> Edges often have data associated with them. ***Arbitrary data can associated with edges as an edge attribute. If the data is numeric and the intent is to represent a weighted graph then use the ‘weight’ keyword for the attribute.*** Some of the graph algorithms, such as Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm, use this attribute name to get the weight for each edge.

A possible implementation in your case would be:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()

for line in file:
    a, b, w = map(int, line.strip().split(' '))
    G.add_edge(a, b, weight=w)
```